# Azure App Service Plan inconsistently throttling - App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription

Tags: azure, terraform, throttling, azure-app-service-plans

When creating an App Service Plan on my new-ish (4 day old) subscription using Terraform, I immediately get a throttling error

`App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription <subscription>. Please contact support if issue persists`

The thing is, when I then go to the UI and create an identical service plan, I receive no errors and it creates without issue, so it's clear that there is actually no throttling issue for creating the app service plan since I can make it.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is occurring?

**NOTE**

I've gotten around this issue by just creating the resource in the UI and then importing it into my TF state... but since the main point of IaC is automation, I'd like to ensure that this unusual behavior does not persist when I go to create new environments.

**EDIT**

My code is as follows

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "frontend_rg" {
  name     = "${var.env}-${var.abbr}-frontend"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "frontend_sp" {
  name                = "${var.env}-${var.abbr}-sp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.frontend_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.frontend_rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.15.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: good question! I've updated to include it

Comment: Great, and which provider version are you using?

Comment: updated w/ version

Comment: Not an Azure expert at all, but the code looks fine to me and as far as I can see, the provider version did have all the arguments you are using.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/623816/out-of-sudden-no-longer-able-to-deploy-more-azure.html

According to this persons experience, some threat detection stuff triggered and Microsoft deployed "countermeasures" which stopped them from being able to deploy them.. perhaps it's the same issue here. I just wish there was _some_ level of transparency on this because I'm left guessing. I haven't done anything "suspicious" or strange. Probably a different issue since I believe I can deploy in different locations